# Does a HashMap collision cause a resize?

Tags: java, hashmap, hash-collision

When there is a collision during a put in a HashMap is the map resized or is the entry added to a list in that particular bucket?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you say 'collision', do you mean the same hashcode? The hashcode is used to determine what bucket in a HashMap is to be used, and the bucket is made up of a linked list of all the entries with the same hashcode. The entries are then compared for equality (using .equals()) before being returned or booted (get/put).

Note that this is the HashMap specifically (since that's the one you asked about), and with other implementations, YMMV.

Comment: And as an added note: if you're curious about how an implementation works, why not just download the source code and look at it? It's available here: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp under 'Additional Resources'.

Answer (score 2):

Either could happen - it depends on the fill ratio of the HashMap.

Usually however, it will be added to the list for that bucket - the HashMap class is designed so that resizes are comparatively rare (because they are more expensive).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`java.util.HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) explains exactly when the map is resized:

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: *initial capacity* and *load factor*.
>
> The *capacity* is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created.
>
> The *load factor* is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased.
>
> **When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is *rehashed* (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.**

The default initial capacity is 16, the default load factor is 0.75. You can supply other values in the map's constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Resising is done when the load factor is reached.

When there is a collision during a put in a HashMap the entry is added to a list in that particular "bucket". If the load factor is reached, the Hashmap is resized.