# Does the implementation of HasMap store key-value pairs in a linked list

Tags: java

I read in a book where it was mentioned that when we put elements in HashMap, internally it is stored in bucket. My question is

1. Does hashmap store key-value pair altogether in the form of linked list? or does it store in linked list only when there is a collision?
2. How does it retrieve the object when 2 different objects are stored in the same bucket?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HashMap collision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239345/hashmap-collision)

Comment: My question is very specific that does it have linked list even when there is no collision?

Comment: This could be useful:  http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html#.ThYUH2GqLFk

Comment: To know more about all these things read my [Internal life of HashMap](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashmap-in-java.html) tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

See also [Internal implementation of java.util.HashMap and HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781868/internal-implementation-of-java-util-hashmap-and-hashset)

And of course you can use the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html), Luke.

Updated: to specifically answer your Q, it stores an Entry, which has a reference to the next item in the bucket (if any). If there is only one item in the bucket then the reference will be null:

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
final K key;
V value;
Entry<K,V> next;
```

Comment: Let's say if I add only 1 item & its going to unique bucket with unique hash code, then in this case, how this bucket stores the key-value pair? Does it still store in the form of linked list or how exactly?

Comment: There will be a single Entry, containing the key and the value, but the 'next' variable will be null. This is a linked list for the special case of only one entry, i.e. there are no links!

Answer (score 3):

The data type of the bucket Array is `Map.Entry`.  When multiple entries fall in the same bucket they are stored in what is conceptually a unidirectional linked list, by holding references to the next Entry.  Just the Entry at the 'head' is inside the array that is the buckets.  However, there is never any use a `java.util.LinkedList` or some actual list class.  The entries just form a list in and of themselves by holding references to their bucket-mates.

When there's more than one in a bucket, it starts with the one that's actually in the `Map.Entry[]`, which is the head of the list, and just starts traversing and checking `.equals()` until it finds a match or next is null.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to understand is by tracing source

- In eclipse If configured jdk hit `ctrl+shift+T` type `HashMap` and `AbstractMap`
- [`AbstractMap`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/AbstractMap.java.html) and [`HashMap`](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm)

You only need to do it once !