# HashMap put method

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm having some trouble when using `.put(Integer, String)` in Java.
To my understanding, when a collision happens the `HashMap` asks whether the `to` value are the same with `.equals(Object)` and if they are not the two values are stored in a `LinkedList`. Nevertheless, `size()` is 1 and the hash iterator only shows one result, the last one.

Apart form this, java `HashMap` API states:put

> ```
> public V put(K key, V value)
> ```
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced.

THIS IS NOT WHAT I HAVE READ EVERYWHERE.

Thoughts?

```
public class HashProblema {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> hash= new HashMap();
        hash.put(1, "sdaaaar");
        hash.put(1, "bjbh");

        System.out.println(hash.size());
        for (Object value : hash.values()) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a collision though - you're putting in the same value, so you're just overwriting the key.

Comment: "the two values are stored in a linked list" - why would you even think this? Where is that documented or stated?

Comment: @Stewart I think it's a reference to some descriptions of some implementations of a hash map when there's a linked list after the various hashed buckets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239345/hashmap-collision

Comment: @EvanKnowles The implementation of HashMaps in java regarding collisions is to use `Separate chaining` rather than `Open Addressing`.

Comment: Don;t look anywhere...look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-  "Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced."

Comment: That. The chaining works for hash collisions, not key collisions. If two _different_ keys have the same _hash_ then internally a linked list will be used. This is just an implementation detail for you, though, and you should not observe any of it publicly.

Comment: `THIS IS NOT WHAT I HAVE READ EVERYWHERE.`. Where is this `EVERYWHERE` that you're referring to?

Answer (score 2):

The output is -:

```
1
bjbh
```

Since the mapping for the key exist, it is replaced and the size remains 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

The value gets over written by the new key..the size remains one and the value gets changed..This is how it works, as key values are always unique..You can't map multiple values on 1 key.

Answer (score 0):

The API is the definitive reference and that is what you must believe.

A collision occurs when the hash of of a key already exists in the HashMap.  Then the values of the *keys* are compared, and if they are the different, the entries are placed in a linked list.  If the keys are the same, then the old key-value in the HashMap is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

API documentation should normally be treated as authoritative unless there is very good reason to doubt its accuracy.

You should almost certainly ignore any claim that doesn't flag itself as 'knowingly' at odds with documentation and provide a testable evidence.

I humbly suggest you might be confused about the role of a linked 'collision' list. As it happens `HashMap` in Java uses a linked-list to store multiple values for which the **hash-code** of the key is placed in the same 'bucket' as one or more other keys.

Answer (score -1):

A HashMap in Java will always store a Key-Value-Pair. There are no linked lists involved. What you are describing is the general idea of a hash map (often taught in computer science class), but the implementation in Java is different. Here, you will always have one value per key only (the last one you put in that place).

However, you are free to define a HashMap that contains List objects. Though, you have to keep track of duplicates and collisions on your own then

Comment: I think the Java Hash-Map IS a Comp Sci. 'Data Structures 101' Hash Map implementation! It uses an array of linked-lists to handle the case where two or more keys go to the same bucket. Textbook. I think the OP is slightly confused between behavior (how it behaves) and implementation (how it works).

Comment: Still, there is only *one* value per key, not a linked list. That's what the OP messed up, I think. It is the keys that are hashed, not the values.